# Nextcloud in docker Exit Code 127

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I want to start nextcloud and mariadb on docker with a compose file. If I use the following line, there's an error:

```
command: –-transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
```

> db_nextcloud exited with code 127

If I don't use this parameters, it works, but I think, this parameters are necessary?

Here the compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db_nextcloud: 
    container_name: db_nextcloud
    image: linuxserver/mariadb:arm32v7-latest
    restart: always 
    command: –-transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mariadbnextcloud2:/var/lib/mysql 
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud 
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
  
  nextcloud: 
    container_name: nextcloud
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - db_nextcloud
    ports: 
      - 8080:80 
    links: 
      - db_nextcloud 
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/nextcloud2:/var/www/html 
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=q&zxTmQf 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud 
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=mariadbnextcloud
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that [linuxserver's Dockerfile](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-mariadb/blob/master/Dockerfile) allows passing command line options for the mariadb-daemon? As far as I can see on a *quick* review those arguments are passed to the `/init` binary but not actively forwarded to the mariadbd. The [original mariadb Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.5/Dockerfile) provides an `ENTRYPOINT` where you can easily pass parameters like this. All matches I could find with `–-transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW` are based on the original mariadb-image.

Additionally, the exit code 127 is used by bash to indicate a file-not-found error - but could also come from `/init` to indicate something completely different.